# Visual Studio 2012 Project has been modified outside environment prompt

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that contains multiple projects, one of which is a website.  Every time I open the solution, VS complains that the website project has been modified outside of the environment.  I've tried deleting the .suo file as suggested in the linked question, and that fixes it for the next time I open the solution, but after that I get the prompt every time again.

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166007/visual-studio-2012-says-website-projects-project-file-is-edited-outside-of-envi), but the suggestions there don't work for me.

Comment: Are you using Source control (TFS, SVN, Source Safe etc), and in that case, is the suo file checked in? In that case, exclude it from source control and try again.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.  Yes, I'm using TFS.  The .suo file does not appear to be checked in.  I don't see it listed in Source Control Explorer anyway.

Comment: I noticed I had two `.suo`-files: `.suo` and `.v11.suo`.  Did you remove both?  Maybe this is related by working in both VS2010 and VS2012?  Or by opening 'old' VS2010-solutions in VS2012 the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Is your solution placed on a mapped **network drive**?

**Solution: Move your project/solution to a local drive.**

I had a similar problem and opening it from my local drive is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but considering how our industry is ever moving towards tele commuting I figured I would throw this out there.

I work for a state organization that works from home 97% of the time.  I use a VPN, and we use o365 for mostly everything.  We are currently using VSS and will be eventually moving to VSTS for source control which is great... but in the off chance of a machine failure, we use OneDrive to sync/secure our local instances of code so that if our laptop dies and we forgot to check in... it isn't the end of the world.

Even though it isn't technically a network location (It sits in a folder in my user profile) it still regularly gives me the File Change Detected message as the folder syncs.

Since it is really annoying to deal with every 10 minutes or so, I've turned actually turned it off. (VS2012 Tools > Options > Environment > Documents)