# "the project has been modified outside the environment ,press reload to load the update project from disk"

Tags: web, publish, webdeploy

I am trying to use webdeploy to publish a website in VS2012. I can publish  but it keeps giving me the following message:

"The project has been modified outside the environment, press reload to load the update project from disk"

I can publish a asp.net web api successfully with the same setting.

Comment: I will be listening to this thread too as I have the same problem. Might be worth noticing that I use ReSharper and .NET Reflector inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Me too, I have Resharper 7 and TFS (free hosted version)

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this too and found that the [accepted answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166009/1036274) resolved my issue.

To be specific: I closed VS, renamed my .suo file, then reopened the solution. VS regenerated a .suo file (~ half the size of the old one).  No more "modified outside..." messages when publishing!

Comment: This worked great. I renamed the .suo file and the problem went away. It created a new .suo file when I told VS 2012 to "Close Solution".